# FQL Query capabilities

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Just getting started with FQL and Graph API.

Is there a way to run a query that performs the same kind of search that you would do on Facebook Graph Search?

For example, user logs in with FB. She wants to find all users named Lisa Smith who live in Florida (regardless of their connection to her). Can the app search for all users in Florida with the first name "Lisa" and last name "Smith", without relating the query to specific userId?

Answer (score 1):

**refer to:** http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

Search is available via the graph api, but there is not a connection via FQL documented.

Some queries you can emulate, but the FQL tables do not provide indexing or tables in some areas.

Searching users via fql. 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20uid%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20732484576

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = 732484576

{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 732484576
    }
  ]
}
```

---

note shawnsspace is my username for facebook and should return my uid, since username is documented as indexed.

```
   SELECT uid,name,birthday,about_me FROM user WHERE username = 'shawnsspace'

{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 732484576, 
      "name": "Shawn E Carter", 
      "birthday": null, 
      "about_me": "Find Me @ \nhttp://facebook.com/AnotherFeed/\nhttp://facebook.com/DesignbyShawn"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

If you are just wanting to fql user profile info, then use:

```
SELECT uid,name,birthday,about_me FROM user WHERE uid = 732484576
```

additional connections: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

Comment: I understand that you can search via graph, but my question is regarding the kind of query I described. Is it doable or not?

Comment: you can query with in stream table to emulate search?q=***&type=post

Comment: But that only applies to posts, right? So there's no way to get actual user info like name, address etc?

Comment: First you would need permissions to request user info, then you have to query by the user's id, so searching users is out of question. "the only indexed connection for user.
uid - number The user ID
username - string - The user's username

Comment: can you query based on a mutual friend and get results with users who are not your friend (but share a mutual friend)?

Comment: of course you cannot get the address and other personal data of people who aren´t even using your app. now that would be a major privacy problem ;)